# Adding configuration file in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to use the [python Amazon-Product-API](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-usage.html) on Elastic Beanstalk. The problem is that I need to add a config file (`~/.amazon-product-api`) to make that API work as per the instructions:

```
[Credentials]
access_key = <your access key>
secret_key = <your secret key>
associate_tag = <your associate id>
```

I can ssh into the instance and put that the file there, but I don't believe that will carry over to new instances when they're brought on line. Is there a way I can tell it to add that file to the right place every time an instance is started?

Incidentally, I've only used this on Windows 7 before. On a Linux EC2 instance, where exactly should I put the config file in the file structure?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Specify the location of the [config file](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#using-files)
2. Pass a [config dict](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#using-config-dict) to the constructor

Comment: Ah those are much easier options. Thanks a lot.